# Dual Video Cards, older (PCI bus) and higher end (GPU bus), does that impair the newer one?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, pci

I want to have 3 monitors setup but the third doesn't need to be hi performance. It's mostly for older video games (that don't display well on a hi res LCD, like Start Craft).

If I mix a newer Video Card, like a:
256MB NVIDIA® Quadro® NVS 295, 2MON

And

an older PCI-slot video card video card

Is that going to degrade the performance of the newer card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could affect the performance of the newer card because they all share the same bus to the processor (on a 1P system). I wouldn't expect it to be noticeable, though. The processor bus bandwidth is much much higher than the PCI card bandwidth

Comment: What is a 1 P system?  (1 CPU ?)

Comment: Yes. 1P = 1 processor socket -- a typical desktop/mobile motherboard. On a 2P or higher system, the PCIe video card could be off a different processor than the PCI card (at least with AMD architecture -- I'm not sure about Intel Quickpath) and then there wouldn't be using the same processor bus.